# Alguem sabe me explicar a seguinte situação:

Tags: javascript, for, objetos

```
pessoa = {
    nome: 'leandro',
    idade: '2'
}
for(x=0;x<pessoa.idade;x++){
   console.log('Ola mundo');     // ele repete 2 vezes "Ola mundo" na tela
}
```

A dúvida que eu tenho é que pensei que o JavaScript diferenciava string de números, mais parece que eu me enganei pois quando eu boto string no objeto ele aceita normalmente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o @Andrew respondeu, o `Javascript` faz conversões implícitas para resolver certas situações. Onde é possível realizar operações como `String`, ele opera como tal, senão ele converte.

Veja abaixo alguns exemplos práticos:

```js
var a = "5";
var b = 2;
var c = 5;

// confirmando os tipos:
console.log('Tipo de a: ' + typeof a);
console.log('Tipo de b: ' + typeof b);
console.log('Tipo de c: ' + typeof c);

// é possível operar como string, concatena:
console.log(a+b)
// não é possível operar como string, divide:
console.log(a/b)
// é possível operar como string, compara os dois como string:
console.log(a == c);
// não é possível operar como string, converte para número:
console.log(a < b);
```

Comment: vlw mano tou começando umas duas semanas ainda tou me adaptando ao JS

Answer (score 1):

O **Javascript** diferencia `string` de números sim. Mas ele está fazendo um trabalho automático que você está deixando passar.

No momento em que você faz:

```
x < pessoa.idade
```

O Javascript sabe que o operador de `<` faz mais sentido comparando números, então por de traz dos panos ele está fazendo isso pra você:

```
x < parseInt(pessoa.idade)
```

Bem vindo ao JS, uma das linguagens mais flexíveis do mundo.

Espero que tenha entendido.

Abraços.

Comment: vlw mano por ter ajudado ainda tou meio perdido a isso faz duas semanas q tou treinando.abraços

Answer (score 1):

Em termos de comparação, o JavaScript sempre vê uma string numérica como um número. No seu caso, o número 2 é visto como um valor a ser comparado, não importa se ele é uma string ou não.

Exceto em casos de operações matemáticas, o JavaScript irá considerar o tipo em caso de soma, por causa do sinal `+` que é usando também em concatenação. Exemplo:

```js
pessoa = {
    nome: 'leandro',
    idade: '2'
}
console.log(pessoa.idade+1); // imprime 21
```

Para somar o valor seria necessário converter a string em número usando, por exemplo, `parseInt()`:

```js
pessoa = {
    nome: 'leandro',
    idade: '2'
}

console.log(parseInt(pessoa.idade)+1); // imprime 3
```

No caso de subtrações, divisões e multiplicações, o valor será considerado um número absoluto:

```js
pessoa = {
   nome: 'leandro',
   idade: '2.    '
}

console.log(pessoa.idade-1); // subtração: imprime 1
console.log(pessoa.idade/2); // divisão: imprime 1
console.log(pessoa.idade*3); // multiplicação: imprime 6
```

Veja que o valor em `idade` eu coloquei um ponto e vários espaços. O JavaScript irá converter o valor da string em valor absoluto. Como ponto é o separador de decimais e os espaços são ignorados, o valor absoluto da string será apenas `2`.

Comment: vlw mano um dia chego lá mais por enquanto é só estudo. Forte abraço tamojunto